# Wall-E Legs mechanism

Tags: mechanism

I was trying to understand the mechanism of Wall-E's Legs from the Wall-E 3D animation movie of Pixar Animation Studios, how he is able to move up and down and move the tracks on all directions. Can anyone explain how or point me to some resource?, I've been searching for days or watching slow motion scenes from movies but still I don't get the big picture of it.

Comment: are you talking about a character in a movie? ... do not assume that the Wall-E movie prop is fully functional and is able to do everything you see in the movie ... the leg raising could be done manually ... any close ups of the leg raising action could be done with a prop that has no other functionality except to extend the legs

Comment: @jsotola, yes it's the Wall-E movie character...

Comment: But it seems to be pretty practical and can be implemented looking at slow motion of the scenes, I could get a guess about the mechanism, but still not the whole picture,

Comment: yes, all you can do is guess ... it is unclear what you mean by `whole picture` ... maybe there isn't one

Comment: I meant to see all components of the legs fitting together and working those movement, up & down, collapsing and extending..probably you are right since after it is a 3D character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an appropriate question over at movies SE, but even here its probably interesting. Wall-Es character is definitely an interesting one, very dynamic, anthropomorphic, and modelled quite realistic.

However there is a lot of film trickery going on here. Although Wall-E and other movie robots like Terminator seem like real mechanical systems, there are a lot of cgi clean up going on behind the scenes or scenes are planned in such a way that holding brackets and such are hidden, or things are designed in a way to terminate on faces of other models, but internally are simply non existing. This is Wall-Es case. It‘s modelled exactly enough to look mechanically feasible, but as you‘ve noticed it would be *very* difficult or impossible to create all his movements.